# JQuery Ajax call to PHP page not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have seen many posts but still not able to figure out why this code is not working. I have a **user_dashboard.html** which contains the code:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();

    $('#search_button').click( function() {
        $.get("db_test2.php", function(data, status) {
            console.log("Test Log");
            alert("Data:"+data+"\nStatus:"+status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The db_test2.php is a file present in the same folder and contains the code:-

```
<?php
    echo "This is a db test";
?>
```

The problem is that I am not getting any alert and no console logs are being generated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your debugger?

Comment: Observe the Network/Net tab in your browser developer tools (F12), to see what the response code and response content is. The success function will only fire for "successful" responses, ie in the 2xx range.

Comment: your code just works fine for me

Comment: check if you have included jquery library properly

Comment: When I click on the submit button I see that nothing happens in the Chrome Network tab @MrCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a submit button, so by default after running your click handler, it will submit the form immediately. To prevent this, you can `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$('#search_button').click( function() {
    $.get("db_test2.php", function(data, status) {
        console.log("Test Log");
        alert("Data:"+data+"\nStatus:"+status);
    });
    return false; // stop the form being submitted
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, put a `console.log("clicked");` to make sure the method is being called

```
$('#search_button').click( function() {
    console.log("clicked"); // here
    $.get("db_test2.php", function(data, status) {
        console.log("Test Log");
        alert("Data:"+data+"\nStatus:"+status);
    });
});
```

EDIT

Works fine on my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7VM8/)

If `db_test2.php` is within the same directory as the file you're in, try putting the whole url

e.g. `www.domain.co.uk/directory/db_test2.php`

if it works then you know that is it not finding `db_test2.php` and that is where your issue is.

Also, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: I added the console.log as you suggested. I can see the message in the console log but only for a second after that the message is gone.Is it ok or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would insert the following alerts earlier in the code, to try and track the problem:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function (e) {

      alert('#search_button').length);//to confirm the presence of the button

      $('#search_button').click( function() {

      alert('Button clicked!');

      $.get("db_test2.php", function(data, status) {
        console.log("Test Log");
        alert("Data:"+data+"\nStatus:"+status);
});
});
});
</script>
```

So, apart from your "Test Log", I assume there's no other Javascript error on the console?
And finally, reconfirm that your 'db_test2.php' is indeed where you thought it was, 'cause a 404 error can often cause this kind of silent, frustrating error!